# pg_config, ruby pg, postgresql 9.0 problem after upgrade, centos 5

Tags: ruby, postgresql, rubygems, centos5, pg

After upgrade postgresql 8.1 to 9.0 ive noticed issues with libraries dependency. Postgresql works fine (connection, queries).

```
yum list postgresql*
Installed Packages
postgresql.i386 9.0.0-1PGDG.el5 installed
postgresql-debuginfo.i386 9.0.0-1PGDG.el5 installed
postgresql-devel.i386 9.0.0-1PGDG.el5 installed
postgresql-libs.i386 9.0.0-1PGDG.el5 installed
postgresql-odbcng.i386 0.90.101-2.el5 installed
postgresql-plruby.i386 0.5.1-5.el5 installed
postgresql-server.i386 9.0.0-1PGDG.el5 install
```

but when im trying to install 'pg' for ruby, ive received

```
gem install pg
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing pg:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/usr/local/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for pg_config... no
checking for libpq-fe.h... no
Can't find the 'libpq-fe.h header
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.
```

When trying with another ruby-postgres driver, ive got

```
yum install ruby-postgres
ruby-postgres-0.7.1-5.el5.i386 from epel has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: libpq.so.4 is needed by package ruby-postgres-0.7.1-5.el5.i386 (epel)
```

and

```
locate libpq.so.4
/usr/lib/libpq.so.4
/usr/lib/libpq.so.4.1
```

also exported path

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/pgsql-9.0/lib
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

after running ruby script with "require pg" (works on 8.1), ive got:

```
/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/i686-linux/pg_ext.so: libpq.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory - /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/i686-linux/pg_ext.so (LoadError)
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:29:in `require'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/pg.rb:12
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:29:in `gem_original_require'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:29:in `require'
```

Any suggestions what to do more?

Answer (score 6):

There are various config options you can add to the gem install, like `-with-opt-dir`, `--with-pg-dir` and `--with-pg-config`. Look at this mailing list thread:

http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/409608

Comment: gem install pg -- --with-pgsql-lib=/usr/pgsql-9.0/lib --with-pg-config=/usr/pgsql-9.0/bin/pg_config , it solves pg installation, thank You! But still after runinng scripts ive got missing libpq.so.4...

Comment: Any progress on this? Maybe update your question so we'll be better able to help you?

Answer (score 5):

```
$ gem --version
1.3.7

$ ruby --version
ruby 1.9.2p180 (2011-02-18 revision 30909) [x86_64-linux]

$ cat /etc/redhat-release 
CentOS release 5.4 (Final)

$ uname -m
x86_64

sudo yum list installed | grep postgre    (see what you have installed)
sudo yum list available | grep postgre    (I was missing postgresql-devel)
sudo yum install postgresql-devel         (I installed it)
sudo gem install pg                       (no error this time!)

$ gem list --local | grep pg
pg (0.11.0)
```

Comment: I had the same scenario while trying to install `pg` gem on CentOS with pre-existing `postgres` installation. I suspect the problem is that `pg_config` could not be located, since I did not have it at all on my system. After installing `postgresql-devel` a `pg_config` was added and `pg` gem installed successfully.

Answer (score 3):

This seems like a pg config file location error,

```
gem install pg -- --with-pgsql-lib=/usr/pgsql-9.0/lib --with-pg-config=/usr/pgsql-9.1/bin/pg_config
```

solves it!!

```
gem install pg -- --with-pgsql-lib=/usr/pgsql-9.0/lib --with-pg-config=/usr/pgsql-9.1/bin/pg_config

/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/yaml.rb:56:in `<top (required)>':
It seems your ruby installation is missing psych (for YAML output).
To eliminate this warning, please install libyaml and reinstall your ruby.
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Successfully installed pg-0.14.0
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for pg-0.14.0...
Installing RDoc documentation for pg-0.14.0...
```

Comment: you probably meant for those pgsql-9.X versions to match up

Answer (score 1):

On Mac OSX 10.6.8, using the MacPorts install of Postgres 9, the following command worked for me:

```
gem install pg -- --with-pgsql-lib=/opt/local/lib/postgresql90/lib --with-pg-config=/opt/local/lib/postgresql90/bin/pg_config
```

Answer (score 0):

*libpq.so.4* is from an older version of PostgreSQL; 9.0 ships with */usr/pgsql-9.0/lib/libpq.so.5*

If you have a program that was built against libpq.so.4, that file is provided by the **compat-postgresql-libs** packages, which you may not have installed.  A lot of people remove it using "--force" because it can be hard to get the newer RPMs installed otherwise; that's a bad idea, but the alternative is [complicated](http://www.westnet.com/~gsmith/content/postgresql/pgrpm.htm).  If you've installed that package, you should find a */usr/lib/libpq.so.4* available that makes your existing program, compiled originally for the older PostgreSQL, happy.