# Missing dependency libpq.so.4 on Centos 5

Tags: postgresql, redhat, centos5, yum, libpq

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [pg_config, ruby pg, postgresql 9.0 problem after upgrade, centos 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4707401/pg-config-ruby-pg-postgresql-9-0-problem-after-upgrade-centos-5)

This is driving me mad.

I'm tring to install postgresql on a fresh Centos 5 installation and I get that dependency error when I do

```
yum install postgresql.
```

I get a similar error when I do

```
yum update
```

Can anyone suggest a solution?

OS is: Linux Centos 5, i686

postgresql-libs is installed.

Comment: libpg is the C client library for postgres, which should be included in the rpm you are trying to install. I suppose that you could try dl'ing the rpm and decompile it to see if that library is present.

Comment: the problem is that libpq.so.4 is installed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably the same problem as this issue, which is why I always (make) install mine from source to avoid package management problems like this:

[pg_config, ruby pg, postgresql 9.0 problem after upgrade, centos 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4707401/pg-config-ruby-pg-postgresql-9-0-problem-after-upgrade-centos-5)